# can't read ts video stream with opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to read gstreamer stream of a *.ts video with a python script using opencv.

Streaming and capturing the stream from terminal (like shown below) is working fine:
stream the video

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="../20200319170208.ts" ! tsparse set-timestamps=true ! video/mpegts ! tsdemux ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse disable-passthrough=true ! rtph264pay ! udpsink -v host=127.0.0.1 port=9999
```

capturing the video stream

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=9999 ! application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H264\,\ packetization-mode\=\(string\)1\,\ profile-level-id\=\(string\)640029\,\ sprop-parameter-sets\=\(string\)\"Z2QAKa2UZHY7isRESjI7HcViIiUZHY7isREUIis3NmmoRFZubNNQiKzc2aaURM0bm8V8n5P5vyfJ5OTNJRpGicnr5P1/J+vk9cmpDyoDIE35cB9QEBAUAAAu4AAK/II8IhGo\\\,aO48sA\\\=\\\=\"\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)3937981927\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)1855247040\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)26643\,\ a-framerate\=\(string\)30 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! glimagesink
```

The python script I'm using to read the video stream using opencv:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

cap_receive = cv2.VideoCapture('udpsrc port=9999 caps= "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, packetization-mode=(string)1, profile-level-id=(string)640029, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z2QAKa2UZHY7isRESjI7HcViIiUZHY7isREUIis3NmmoRFZubNNQiKzc2aaURM0bm8V8n5P5vyfJ5OTNJRpGicnr5P1/J+vk9cmpDyoDIE35cB9QEBAUAAAu4AAK/II8IhGo\,aO48sA\=\=\", payload=(int)96" ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

if not cap_receive.isOpened():
    print("videocapture not opened")
    exit(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap_receive.read()

    if not ret:
        print("empty frame")
        break 

    cv2.imshow('receive', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    cap_receive.release()
```

The error I get:

```
(python3.7:10464): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
[ WARN:0] OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: could not set property "caps" in element "udpsrc0" to "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, packetization-mode=(string)1, profile-level-id=(string)640029, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"
[ WARN:0] OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
videocapture not opened
```

I have tried reading different streams using opencv, like the one of the builtin webcam and managed to do it successfully.

**Update**
I have changed the cap_receive line to match more the bash command that worked,

```
cap_receive = cv2.VideoCapture('udpsrc port=9999 ! application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, packetization-mode=(string)1, profile-level-id=(string)640029, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"Z2QAKa2UZHY7isRESjI7HcViIiUZHY7isREUIis3NmmoRFZubNNQiKzc2aaURM0bm8V8n5P5vyfJ5OTNJRpGicnr5P1/J+vk9cmpDyoDIE35cB9QEBAUAAAu4AAK/II8IhGo\,aO48sA\=\=", payload=(int)96 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Here is the output I got:

```
[ WARN:0] OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=1, value=0, duration=-1
empty frame
```

I should add for another example of capturing a stream of the built-in webcam, while it worked it still outputs this line:

```
[ WARN:0] OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=1, value=0, duration=-1
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm using opencv 3.4.10, python3.7.x and ubuntu 16.04

PS: please, if you wanna flag this question, leave a feedback that helps me fix it, thanks

Comment: Note that there is a difference between your example pipeline, and the one that you actually use in your code (`udpsrc port=9999 ! application/x-rtp,....` vs `udpsrc port=9999 caps=application/x-rtp,... ! `)

Comment: @nielsdg yeah that's right, I updated it afterwards, and forgot to update the question.
I thought maybe I unescaped that string incorrectly

Comment: question updated*